# Text annotations in matplotlib on next line (linebreak) using '\n' give a square box instead of a line break

Tags: matplotlib, plot-annotations

I tried to create text annotations in **matplotlib** using **\n**, on the plot instead of a line break it is showing a square box

```
 "Fault location:" + str(sc) + "\nI_sc=" + str(fault)
```

I wanted to Fault location and I_sc in separate line like

```
Fault location: 1
I_sc=2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [Accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sc = 1
fault = 2

plt.annotate(f'Fault location: {str(sc)}\nI_sc={str(fault)}', xy=(0.5, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Returns

[image]